# facing problems while adding div between slick.js slides

Tags: html, jquery, css, angular, slick.js

I am using slick.js with Angular and trying very hard to add custom div that has dashed border after every image in slick slider (it needs to be placed right between the gaps of two slides). I am implementing slick slider with vertical scroll as illustrated below:

[image]

(**P.S.** Above image is depiction of a slider implemented in vertical format. I am not used to picture editing tool on the Linux so that's why I took image from slick website and rotated it vertically to explain my purpose)

Black dotted lines in the above image denotes a custom div with black borderline which looks exactly like what is mentioned in image below, after it is perfectly implemented between the gaps of two slides:

[image]

I just couldn't figure a way by which I can attach this border with its own separate styling.

**My Code:**

slider-component.component.html

```
<!--slider image container-->
<div #slick class="mySlider" id="images">
  <div class="item image-container" *ngFor="let data of serverData; let ind = index;"
       id="imageContainer">
    <img (load)="imageLoaded($event.target)"
         src="{{ data['imageUrl'] }}"
         class="img-fluid target slick-img"
         [ngStyle]="{'zoom': zoom}"
         alt="image container"
    >
    <!-- dashed ruler after every image slide -->
    <hr class="dashed-line">
  </div>
</div>
```

slider-component.component.ts

```
  private slickSetting = {
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    centerMode: true,
    centerPadding: '50px',
    arrows: false,
    dots: false,
    vertical: true,
    verticalSwiping: false,
    draggable: false,
  };

  private getSlick(): any{
    return $(this.slick.nativeElement);
  }

  private initializeSlick() {
    let slickElement = this.getSlick();
    slickElement.slick(this.slickSetting);
  }
```

**What I Tried?**

I have tried reading documentation for slick and browsed intensively on google, but nowhere I can find any good solution to this problem.

I also tried css way of giving parent class **position: relative** and dashed line div as **position: absolute** but nothing works. Is there any good way of achieving this?

**Why I am doing this?**

The goal here is not to implement mere dashed border, but to add a custom div between two slides of a slider. This custom div can then be styled to add border, I also want to add some extra options in the future when someone clicks on that div.

**edit1:**

I tried MaxiGui solution below and so far I was able to get the dashed div besides my image like this:

[image]

However, I just want this div to be placed right on the bottom (in the gap between all the images) of this vertical scroll slider.

**Answer is below**

If you are stuck with same problem, please refer to first answer and afterwards my answer below with tweaks based on the earlier answer.

Comment: Are you searching for `border-right-style: dashed; ` ?

Comment: @MaxiGui no not exactly `border-style: dashed`. I want to add a div between two images on slider that can have its own border-style or any style I give. In the case above I want to apply `border-style: dashed`

Comment: @isherwood I tried adding pseudo-element like `:after` after the image container in ngfor loop but that results in styling getting attached in-line with the images. Also by using pseudo-elements I will loose the control of letting user click on that div and triggering function for the same.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your image I would suggest you to use border directly to your images-container and set a rotate to your main container

```css
#images{
  transform:rotate(270deg);
  display:flex;
}
.image-container{
  border-right-style: dashed;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
img{
  max-width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div #slick class="mySlider" id="images">
  <div class="item image-container" *ngFor="let data of serverData; let ind = index;"
       id="imageContainer">
    <img (load)="imageLoaded($event.target)"
         src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/09/09/13/03/bike-riding-5557589_1280.png"
         class="img-fluid target slick-img"
         [ngStyle]="{'zoom': zoom}"
         alt="image container"
    >
    <!-- dashed ruler after every image slide -->
  </div>
  <div class="item image-container" *ngFor="let data of serverData; let ind = index;"
       id="imageContainer">
    <img (load)="imageLoaded($event.target)"
         src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/09/09/13/03/bike-riding-5557589_1280.png"
         class="img-fluid target slick-img"
         [ngStyle]="{'zoom': zoom}"
         alt="image container"
    >

  </div>
</div>
```

With dashed in div sibiling to img:

```css
#images{
  transform:rotate(270deg);
  display:flex;
}
.image-container{
  display:flex;
}

.width-dashed{
  border-right: 3px dashed black;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
img{
  max-width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div #slick class="mySlider" id="images">
  <div class="item image-container" *ngFor="let data of serverData; let ind = index;"
       id="imageContainer">
    <img (load)="imageLoaded($event.target)"
         src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/09/09/13/03/bike-riding-5557589_1280.png"
         class="img-fluid target slick-img"
         [ngStyle]="{'zoom': zoom}"
         alt="image container"
    >
    <!-- dashed ruler after every image slide -->
    <div class="width-dashed"></div>

  </div>
  
  <div class="item image-container" *ngFor="let data of serverData; let ind = index;"
       id="imageContainer">
    <img (load)="imageLoaded($event.target)"
         src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/09/09/13/03/bike-riding-5557589_1280.png"
         class="img-fluid target slick-img"
         [ngStyle]="{'zoom': zoom}"
         alt="image container"
    >
      <!-- dashed ruler after every image slide -->
    <div class="width-dashed"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but as we discussed in comments section I don't want to apply just a dashed border style to the image container, instead would like to add a custom div which can be further styled in our own custom ways. I have also updated my question so that this information is visible in it.

Comment: @Dhruvify Check out the second demo

Comment: @MaxGui Nothing breaks but dashed border is completely missing from the screen. Slider works as usual.

Comment: Is there a live demo to try it out ? because if it works here it should works too by your code

Comment: @MaxGui Sure I will create one live demo shortly and give it a try

Comment: It might be that it does not detect any width so it does not show, try to add width on div and it might appear

Comment: I have updated the question with the results after adding your code. I had to move the scrollbar to far end to see the div that was placed right besides the image. It is on side but not on bottom, so trying to sort that out. Also tried adding code pen but nothing is working there. I have lot of styles that ain't going well with custom codepen.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222247/discussion-between-maxigui-and-dhruvify).

Answer (score 1):

Alright, so this couldn't have been possible without the help of answer that MaxiGui posted above. So as per his answer I was able to get it working by doing some minor fixes. Here are those fixes if anyone gets stuck with same problem:

I just added `absolute` to dashed line and gave it 100% width. Later I removed `position: relative` from image container and marked it as `unset`.

```
.dashed-line{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: -16px;
  border-bottom: 3px dashed #434343;
}

/* image container related */
.image-container {
  width: 90% !important;
  display: flex !important;
  position: unset !important;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

I am now able to perfectly align the custom div with border styling right in the empty middle gaps of two slides using Slick.js.

This is final form (I'll take care of border colour styling later):

[image]

Thank you MaxiGui for your help and feedback.